# EF Core 5 How to stop ValueGeneratedOnAdd being added to all my models

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am migrating from EF Core 2.2 to 5 and use explicit Guids for my ids, ie not generated

This causes error when adding non-tracked child values to an entity

ref: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17747

Is there a way that I can configure the **whole** model to **not** add `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` to my id columns, without explicitly setting it on each one?

```
    public class ParentData
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public IList<ChildData> Children { get; set; } = new List<ChildData>();
    }

    public class ChildData
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
        public ParentData Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ValudGeneratedOnAdd` for `Guid` type PKs is [by convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#primary-keys), and also EF Core currently (v5.x) does not offer a way of modifying conventions, you can use the metadata API to do what you need.

Add the following snippet *at the end* of `OnModelCreating` override (to make sure all entity types have already been discovered):

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ValueGenerated == ValueGenerated.OnAdd
        && p.IsPrimaryKey()
        && p.ClrType == typeof(Guid)))
{
    property.ValueGenerated = ValueGenerated.Never;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I also ended up adding p.Name == "Id" which works for our conventions